# How to center the section headers of a UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I want to center the header on the tableview, however I have 2 problems. First I don't have the correct height and second the UILabel doesn't look like the default header - font/font size/color etc... Is there a better way to center it, and/or is there a way to make it look like the default header.

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger) section
{
    //section text as a label
    UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    lbl.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;  

    lbl.text = @"Header";
    [lbl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];  

    return lbl;
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You must also implement tableView:heightForHeaderInSection to adjust your header height :

In the UITableViewDelegate Protocol Reference doc you find :

> tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:
>
> Discussion
>
> The returned object, for example, can
> be a UILabel or UIImageView object.
> The table view automatically adjusts
> the height of the section header to
> accommodate the returned view object.
> **This method only works correctly when
> tableView:heightForHeaderInSection: is
> also implemented.**

For centering the Header label you must specify the label frame before setting its aligment to center.
For getting the standart font, use SystemFontOfSize:

Also beware **you are creating a memory leak** you are supposed to return an autoreleased view

Try something like this :

```
UILabel *lbl = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 30)] autorelease];
lbl.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
lbl.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
```

Hope this helps,
Vincent

Comment: Thanks, but I still need to find the font size, label height, etc of the actual default header in order to set it as above.... I don't want to change anything from the default header except for the center alignment.  That left alignment just looks so bad for what I'm doing.

Comment: I've accepted this answer as it was very helpful and I've decided not to use the phone's default header font and use my own instead.

Comment: must be self.view.frame.size.width in CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, 30)

Answer (score 26):

this should solve your issue. Tested in xcode 6 / ios8

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    [[UILabel appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UITableViewHeaderFooterView class], nil] setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
    return [sectionTitles objectAtIndex:section];
}
```

Comment: This works great. I had not previously used or seen appearanceWhenContainedIn as a way to find something in the view hierarchy. Ninja trick!

Comment: works ! "appearanceWhenContainedIn" could be taken out of the method and placed in viewDidLoad

Comment: Include the appearanceWhenContainedIn within the application delegate's 
- application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: and it will apply throughout the whole application.

Answer (score 22):

Volker's answer in Swift:

If you target iOS6 and later you don't have to provide your own header view if you just want to center the header title.

Just implement

```
- tableView:willDisplayHeaderView:forSection:
```

and set the textAligment property of the label:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
    if let headerView = view as? UITableViewHeaderFooterView {
        headerView.textLabel?.textAlignment = .Center
    }
}
```

Answer (score 21):

If you target **iOS6 and later** you don't have to provide your own header view if you just want to center the header title.
Just implement

> - tableView:willDisplayHeaderView:forSection:

and set the textAligment property of the label:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayHeaderView:(UIView *)view forSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if([view isKindOfClass:[UITableViewHeaderFooterView class]]){

        UITableViewHeaderFooterView *tableViewHeaderFooterView = (UITableViewHeaderFooterView *) view;
        tableViewHeaderFooterView.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    }
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Using the  [UILabel appearanceWhenContainedIn:UITableViewHeaderFooterView.class...] trick will change *all* your headers in *all* the tableviews in your app

Answer (score 8):

To make this method being called you should first implement

```
titleForHeaderInSection
```

then `tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int)` method will be called

***Swift Solution:***

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
    if let headerView = view as? UITableViewHeaderFooterView {


        headerView.textLabel?.textAlignment = Localize().isRTL ? .Right : .Left
        headerView.textLabel?.text = partsDataSource[section]
        headerView.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor ( red: 0.0902, green: 0.2745, blue: 0.2745, alpha: 1.0 )
        headerView.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: UIDecorator.sharedInstance.PRIMARY_FONT, size: 14.0)
        headerView.contentView.backgroundColor = UIDecorator.sharedInstance.currentTheme.lightShadeColor
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return " "
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's my version, you'll need to take a screenshot of the normal header background, and save a 1px wide slice of it as 'my_head_bg.png' and add it to the project. This way, it'll look just exactly normal:

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    UILabel *lbl = [[[UILabel alloc] init] autorelease];
    lbl.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    lbl.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:18];
    lbl.text = @"My Centered Header";
    lbl.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    lbl.shadowColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    lbl.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0,1);
    lbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"my_head_bg"]];
    lbl.alpha = 0.9;
    return lbl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    UILabel *tableHeader = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 30)];
[tableHeader setText:@"This is header"];
[tableHeader setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];

UITableView *newTable = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 0, 280, 200) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
[newTable setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[newTable setTableHeaderView:tableHeader];
self.view = newTable;
```

Answer (score 1):

In Xamarin:

```
        // Center Header
        public override void WillDisplayHeaderView(UITableView tableView, UIView headerView, nint section)
        {
            if (headerView.GetType() == typeof(UITableViewHeaderFooterView))
            {
                UITableViewHeaderFooterView tableViewHeaderFooterView = (UITableViewHeaderFooterView)headerView;
                tableViewHeaderFooterView.TextLabel.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -4):

To change height, implement this method:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
                        viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return 15;
}
```

I am not really sure about the default header thing - that should be way easier than it is. Maybe someone has a nice background image you can use with a white font.  But for the centering thing, try this:

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,15)];
label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter

label.text = @"Text Should Be Centered";
```

Comment: I think you need to check you code before submit it! the `-viewForHeaderInSection` function returns UIView and can't return 15.

Comment: @HamedRajabi I think I probably meant to return the 15 to whatever the height method is called :P